# How to change one element in array by index in a functional style?

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example, I want to write something like:

```
const initial = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const indexIWantToChange = 2;

const obj = {
  prop: () => {
    const newArr = [...initial];
    newArr[indexIWantToChange] = 'Something new';
    return newArr;
  }()
};
```

How to change one specific element in array by index without mutating the original array in a functional style?
Is there a one-liner of this maybe?

Comment: The array isn't immutable. What immutability are you referring to?

Comment: ...well anyway: `newArr = [...initial.slice(0, idx), 'Something new', ...initial.slice(idx+1)]` Maybe that's what you're after. I can't really tell what you want.

Comment: In languages that aren't inherently functional, trying to force a functional style without the use of a exhaustive library will just be inefficient.

Comment: @revels, take a look at https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) might be useful:

```
Object.assign([], initial, { [indexIWantToChange]: 'Something new' })
```

Snippet:

```js
const initial = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const indexIWantToChange = 2;

let prop = Object.assign([], initial, { [indexIWantToChange]: 'Something new' });

console.log(prop);
```

Comment: This is really clean. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

most things functional that return an array are often done by map

```
const initial = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const indexIWantToChange = 2;
const newValue = "blah"

let changed = initial.map((x,i) => i == indexIWantToChange ? newValue : x )
```

Comment: Yeah that's the one way of doing it, but it goes through a whole array. Maybe some helper function? I haven't find any of this kind in lodash docs.

Comment: @Revels, if with *save immutability* you mean *without mutating the original array*, then you must iterate through the array, which is what the spread operator in your original code does as well. How would you imagine to get a variant of the array without going *through a whole array*?

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of way to do this in a so called functional way. @Keith Nicholas has a nice solution. Since you need a clone array, O(n) time complexity is essential.

Another way would be

```js
var        initial = [1, 2, 3, 4],
indexIWantToChange = 2,
          newValue = "whatever",
           changed = initial.reduce((p,c,i) => i === indexIWantToChange ? p.concat(newValue) : p.concat(c),[]);
console.log(changed);
```